# Parcel write/read doesn't work in AndroidTestCase -why?

Tags: android, testing, null, parcel

I am trying to test to write to a Parcel in Android test but it doesnt't work. s==null! What is wrong?

```
public class scraptest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void test() {

        Parcel parcel=Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.writeString("sdfsdf");
        String s=parcel.readString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One must reset the Parcel's data position with:
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);